# Is it safe to delete the 32-bit Intel code from apps using a tool like Monolingual?

Tags: macos

Using the application [Monolingual](http://monolingual.sourceforge.net/), is it safe to remove the Intel architecture on a Late 2010 MacBook Air and just leave the Intel 64-Bit architecture?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but...

You may develop problems updating certain apps as removing parts of the app using Monolingual can render the code signing of the application incorrect.

From [Switcher's Blog](http://switchersblog.com/2007/11/leopard-code-si.html)

> OS X 10.5 Leopard brings a new Code Signing security feature that helps verify the integrity of an application. Applications are signed by their creators before being distributed using their private key, and then can be verified on the customer's machine using the companies public key.

That's for third party apps. I really wouldn't tempt fate by doing this to system files.

Comment: No, it is not safe actually. Some drivers and kernel extensions still rely on them. Not to mention the odd program (like iTunes' mobiledevicehelper for example). That's for a global removal. As for the removal of independent apps, it is also not safe as it may likely break components. It also results in very little space saving.

Comment: The only thing that is really affected seems to be the Apple Firewall.